# Appending function executed onclick of button

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Alright so essentially I've got a HTML button that executes a given function onclick and once this function is executed I want to append the name of the function executed by clicking that very same button. Evidently this will be the last component of the initial function.

I've attempted conducting research on this particular question of changing the onclick HTML attribute set onto a button with little success and given javascript novelty to me, I have no preexistent knowledge to produce such a function.

Here's the code for the HTML button:

```
    <button id="englishgradesubmit" onClick="Functionenglishgradesubmit()">Submit Grade</button>
```

Heres the corresponding javascript function:

```
    function Functionenglishgradesubmit() {
    var params1 = new Array();

    params1.push(radiobuttonanswer("englishgrade"));
    params1.push(document.getElementById('criterionenglish').value);

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(remake)
      .postit(params1);

      }

    function radiobuttonanswer(englishgrade) {
    var englishgrade = document.getElementsByName(englishgrade);
    theans ="";
    for (var i = 0, length = englishgrade.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (englishgrade[i].checked) {
    theans = englishgrade[i].value;
    break;
}

     }

     if (theans.length == 0) {
  alert("Answer: nothing selected for button" + englishgrade); 
  return -1; 
     }

    return theans;

     }

   function remake() {
  unknown code for the moment;
    }
```

Essentially, the first time the button is clicked the big javascript function above is executed and additionally executes the remake() function that's supposed to change the onclick function of the button to an entirely different function, producing something like the below.

```
     <button id="englishgradesubmit" onClick="otherfunction()">Submit Grade</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getAttribute` to get the `onclick` attribute which contains the name of the function.

```js
function Functionenglishgradesubmit()
{
var a=document.getElementById('englishgradesubmit').getAttribute('onClick');
document.getElementById('englishgradesubmit').removeAttribute('onClick');
document.getElementById('englishgradesubmit').setAttribute('onClick','newFunction()');

var b=document.getElementById('englishgradesubmit').getAttribute('onClick');
//perform the function tasks
document.getElementById('append').innerHTML+="Old Function name is " +'<b>'+a+'</b><br>';
document.getElementById('append').innerHTML+="New Function name is " +'<b>'+b+'</b>';
}
```

```html
<button id="englishgradesubmit" onClick="Functionenglishgradesubmit()">Submit Grade</button>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: Alright that works but then what do I do to actually change the name of the onclick function

Comment: Something like this... const newOnclickValue = functionName + "()"; 
theElement.setAttribute("onclick", newOnclickValue);

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to change onclick function after the big javascript was executed and also append the name of the function, so, you can do something like this:

```
function remake()
{
   var btn = document.getElementById('englishgradesubmit');
   var fname = btn.getAttribute('onclick');
   document.getElementById('append').innerHTML = "function name: " + fname; //append the function name (if needed)
   btn.onclick = otherFunction;
}
```

And in HTML (if needed):

```
<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's essentially what ive done now, thank you Luis.